# HTML5 video - Play event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari, dom-events

I currently have an HTML5 video event issue in Safari.  I am playing a single video on my page.  The video loads and plays correctly.  However, the play event does not always fire.  If the user:

1. Clicks play
2. Watches the video to the end (ended event fires)
3. Clicks play again

The play event does not fire on the second click.  If I pause/play the movie at that time, the correct events fire.

How can I make the video tag's play event fire if the video has completed and the user presses play again?

**drawVidPlayer is called with the videos index as part of the page render**

```
function drawVidPlayer(vindex){
    var turl=vidList[vindex]['thumbUrl'];
    var vurl=vidList[vindex]['url'];
    var valias=vidList[vindex]['type'];
    destroyVidPlayer(); 
    $('#mediaspot').css('backgroundColor', '#000000');
    $('#mediaspot').show();
    $('#mediaspot').html('<video controls="controls" id="twnvideo" poster="'+turl+'" style="height:225px; width:460px;"><source src="'+vurl+'" type="video/ogg" /><source src="'+vurl+'" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+vurl+'" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>').appendTo('#wrap_media_vod');
    var velem=document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];    
    velem.addEventListener('play', initVidTimer, false);
    velem.addEventListener('pause', killVidTimer, false);
    velem.addEventListener('ended', killVidTimer, false);
}    
function destroyVidPlayer(){
    var velem=document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    if(velem!=undefined){
        velem.removeEventListener('play', initVidTimer);
        velem.removeEventListener('pause', killVidTimer);
        velem.removeEventListener('ended', killVidTimer);
    }
    $('#mediaspot').empty();
    $('#mediaspot').html('');
}
function initVidTimer(){
    if(activityTimer==null){
        external.OnUserActivity(19);
        activityTimer=setInterval(function(){
            external.WriteLog('activity timer running');
            external.OnUserActivity(19);
        }, 5000);
    }
}
function killVidTimer(){
    clearInterval(activityTimer);       
    activityTimer=null; // Kill keepAlive timer
    var velem=document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    external.WriteLog(velem.ended);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#playing-the-media-resource) now specifies that the browser *must* throw the `timeupdate`,  `paused`, and `ended` events when the playback position reaches the end of a media file, but the spec wasn't always that clear. As a result, this behavior is inconsistent between browsers. Some don't set `paused=true` or fire the `paused` event when the file ends.

In your Safari issue, `paused` is still equal to `false` when the video starts to play for the second time - so there is no reason for the browser to fire the `play` event again.

This may no longer be an issue in Safari 6, but it still breaks in IE 9. Take a look at the *End Events* column in [this chart](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/playback) from longtailvideo.com - they outline the inconsistencies well.

It would easy to normalize this issue with a couple lines of code - like this:

```
$("video").on("ended", function () {
    if (!this.paused) this.pause();
});
```

This puts the video in the paused state on `ended`, so it will throw the `play` event correctly on replay.

You can try this working sample in IE 9 or to see what I mean on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PWnUb/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I solved with a bit of jquery:

```
function videoend(){
     var duration = $("video").get(0).duration;
     var current = $("video").get(0).currentTime;

    if(current==duration){
        //Whatever you wanna do when video ends
    };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval("videoend()", 200); //or any other time you wanna use
});
```

Hope this helps.